# Payday 2 mask levels as they relate to the Ghost Riders achievement

Tags: achievements, payday-2

The Ghost Riders achievement for Payday 2 states that you have to "Complete a heist while you and your four man crew are wearing one different difficulty mask each".

My question: Do all the different masks have levels? Or is this achievement specifically related to the masks awarded for completing all jobs on Hard, Very Hard, Overkill and Death Wish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The achievement requires wearing [the masks](http://payday.wikia.com/wiki/Masks_%28Payday_2%29#Death_Wish_Update) awarded for completing all jobs on each difficulty.

Specifically, the four masks are called **The Hard Skull**, **The Very Hard Skull**, **The Overkill Skull**, and **The Deathwish Skull**.  Each must be worn by one player during a heist to get the achievement.